# Bypass browser audio processing

Tags: javascript, browser, webrtc, audio-streaming

I've seen a number of posts discussing removal of automatic audio processing in various browsers, usually in connection with WebRTC. The javascript is along the lines of

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: {
    autoGainControl: false,
    channelCount: 2,
    echoCancellation: false,
    latency: 0,
    noiseSuppression: false,
    sampleRate: 48000,
    sampleSize: 16,
    volume: 1.0
  }
});
```

I've set up WebRTC live streaming from my home studio to my website and need to implement this, but I'm unclear on where in the signal chain the constraints are placed.

If I am generating the audio in my studio, and the viewers are watching/listening on my website in a given browser, it seems that the proper place to drop the code would be in the html/javascript on the viewer end, not my end. But if the user is simply observing (not generating any audio of their own), a call to

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia
```

on their end would appear to be inert.

What's the proper method for implementing a javascript snippet on the browser end for removing audio processing? Should this be done instead through the Web Audio API?

Answer (score 1):

These media constraints are audio capture constraints, which are used where you record the audio... on the source end.

Comment: I think that's a DOH moment for me. :-p Thanks for pointing that out.